Как пересылать изображения/медиа пользователя из одного чат-бота в другой?
Записываю логи из основного бота в другой бот, все пишется хорошо, но на изображения дает лишь ссылку, а не само фото. При переходе по ссылке ошибка. Всю голову сломал уже, как же это делается?
Такая ошибка при переходе:
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 404,
  "description": "Not Found"
}


Каким образом передается фото?

Фото отправляется в чат-бот. У меня получилось реализовать путем копирования в буфер, но это не выход, так как на копирование и вставку коду требуется время и от этого логи сходят с ума.

Опишите подробнее вашу задачу. Так ничего не понятно

Есть телеграм бот, он для обработки фото. Юзер отправляет фото основному боту для обработки. Фото отправляется в другой второстепенный бот для того, чтобы уже внешний сервис смог взять эту фотку в работу. Но! Изначально я смог получать только ссылку на это фото, которая не открывалась. В итоге я сделал код, который копирует полученное фото в буфер и отправляет его в нужный бот. Но! Пока код это делает — логи сходят с ума, постоянно отправляя уведомление о доставке фото из буфера текстом "изображение", пока не придет само фото (да, это можно решить проверкой), но это тоже не вариант (буфер).

Если оба бота в телеграм, то напрямую нельзя передать фото - боты не могут взаимодействовать друг с другом
